# How to get path of font file from asset folder and how to use that path to set SKTypeface in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I am working in native xamarin andorid. I am facing issue to set custom font. I am using "SkiaSharp" plugin to generate canvas view. That plugin is inside PCL so that can be use in both android and ios.

**I have one .ttf file in my "Assets" folder.**

I generate font path using following code.

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string FontPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Myfile.ttf");
```

this Path I send to PCL to set **"SKTypeface"**

```
paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFile(FontPath, 0);
```

if it is **"Typeface"** then I can use following approach

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "Myfile.ttf");
```

**I always get null SKTypeface as return value.**

**I think font path is not found.**

```
bool flag=File.Exist(FontPath)
```

it always return null value.

***How to get path of Asset folder in xamarin andorid?
How to set custom font to SKTypeface?***

Comment: paint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial"); its working but custom font not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically don't use the path for the android assets as they are located inside the app package. Rather you get a stream and load that - however asset streams are not seekable, so they have to be copied first:

```cs
SKTypeface typeface;
using (var asset = Assets.Open("Fonts/CONSOLA.TTF"))
{
    var fontStream = new MemoryStream();
    asset.CopyTo(fontStream);
    fontStream.Flush();
    fontStream.Position = 0;
    typeface = SKTypeface.FromStream(fontStream);
}

...
paint.Typeface = typeface;
```

I also want to make a note that this is relatively "slow" so you probably want to do this once and then just re-use the typeface. Avoid loading files directly in the paint methods as the paint happens on the UI thread and will block.

When loading assets, do not include the root "Assets" folder as this is assumed.

**EDIT**

In the new v1.59.2 release, the existing `FromStream` method will work as expected, regardless of the stream.

Comment: Thanks for reply but not working. I got null stream.

Comment: My font file is inside Font folder. Assets/Font/myfile.ttf

Comment: @RutulMehta I re-wrote the answer as I was wrong on the first time. This is not a nice bit of code and I will fix this in the next version of SkiaSharp.

Comment: I got the typeface but FontFamily can't set.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking... You can't set the family of the typeface, the typeface is the family. To load a specific family, use `FromFamilyName`.

Comment: Its Done. thanks for the reply its really appreciable.